# HOWTO implement OLAP cube queries into PHP MYSQL browser App

Tags: php, mysql, olap, olap-cube

We developed a browser app written in PHP and MYSQL using the Smarty template. The data is similar to sales data and can be stored in a OLAP cube format.

Now we would like to offer inside the App a menu for certain users to analyze the sales data directly.
A cube query would offer us the most information for the least effort of programming. So my questions are:

- Do we need to install another server to run cube queries?
- If yes, which one would you recommend and how can we migrate the data?
- How would the visualization in PHP work?

Since we have never implemented any OLAP cube we would be grateful for any kind of advice, literature on how to approach this project.

Comment: Sorry to say, this question does not fit StackOverflow's format, because 1) useful answers would be too broad, 2)  it asks for recommendations, and 3) it asks multiple questions.  The purpose of Stack Overflow is to accumulate a library of useful questions and answers, and that is why we are sticklers about well-formed questions.